# Dealing with asynchronous functions. Custom callback?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have the code below and am trying to access the **all_records** array once the **_.each** function has completed. However as it is asynchronous I was wondering if was possible to force a callback onto the underscores **each**?

```js
var request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    _       = require('underscore');

var all_records = [];

_.each([0,100], function(start) {

  var base_url = "http://www.example.com/search?limit=100&q=foobar&start=";
  var url = base_url + start;

  request(url, function(err, res, body) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body),
      links = $('#results .row');
    $(links).each(function(i, link) {
      var $link = $(link);
      var record = {
        title: $link.children('.title').text().trim()
      };
      all_records.push(record);
    });
  });
});

// Need to run this once _.each has completed final iteration.
console.log(all_records);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution using a [simple synchronization method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_semaphore):

```
var count = 101;//there are 101 numbers between 0 and 100 including 0 and 100
_.each([0,100], function(start) {

  var base_url = "http://www.example.com/search?limit=100&q=foobar&start=";
  var url = base_url + start;

  request(url, function(err, res, body) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body),
      links = $('#results .row');
    $(links).each(function(i, link) {
      var $link = $(link);
      var record = {
        title: $link.children('.title').text().trim()
      };
      all_records.push(record);
      count--;
      if(count===0){//101 iterations done
         console.log(all_records);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

A more elegant solution can be accomplied by using [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async)'s `.parallel` method.

```
var requests = []; //an array for all the requests we will be making

for(var i=0;i<=100;i++){
   requests.push((function(done){ //create all the requests
       //here you put the code for a single request. 
       //After the push to all_records you make a single done() call 
       //to let async know the function completed
   }).bind(null,i));//the bind is that so each function gets its own value of i   
}
async.parallel(requests,function(){
    console.log(all_records);
});
```

Comment: async was the way to go but I ended up using async.forEach in the end.

Comment: Great, if this solution solved your problem, please consider accepting this answer. Also, I think you meant async.each and not foreach.

Comment: Yes, it is each according to the docs. Although forEach works also.

Answer (score 0):

**async.each** ended up being the easiest to implement.

```js
async.each([0,100], function(start) {
  var base_url = "http://www.example.com/search?limit=100&q=foobar&start=";
  var url = base_url + start;

  request(url, function(err, res, body) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body),
      links = $('#results .row');
    $(links).each(function(i, link) {
      var $link = $(link);
      var record = {
        title: $link.children('.title').text().trim()
      };
      all_records.push(record);
    });
  });
}, function(err){
  console.log(all_records);
});
```